# Can I use DataGridView without using database data?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, client-server

I have a client-server program and the server receives [Process ID, Hostname, App Name, File Path] and I want to put them in a table. As of now they are sent in one string. Is DataGridView applicable to use even if they are not inside a database or is there another option?

Thanks.

Comment: what does the string look like !! can you add a sample record.

Comment: slr. it sends this SENT DATA : 
 4836
 Client_PC.vshost.exe
 Client_PC
 C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Client_PC\Client_PC\bin\Debug\Client_PC.vshost.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is Yes.

- You can use a `List<T>` as `DataSource`
- You can use a `DataTable` as `DataSource` (DataTable not related to db)
- You can use it without `DataSource` and only defining columns and adding rows

**Use with `List<T>` as `DataSource` for example:**

```
var data= new List<DataClass>();
data.Add(new DataClass(){Property1=1 , Property2= "One"   });
data.Add(new DataClass(){Property1=2 , Property2= "Two"   });
data.Add(new DataClass(){Property1=3 , Property2= "Three" });

dataGridView1.DataSource= data;
```

And the result will be a dataGridView with 2 columns (Property1, property2) and 3 rows.

In above example, `DataClass` is a class like the following:

public class DataClass
{
    public int Property1 {get; set;}
    public string Property2 {get; set;}
}

For more advance scenarios you can use DataSource window to add new DataSource to your project. You can add Object datasource as well.

**use with a `DataTable` as `DataSource`**

You can create a `DataTable` and add your columns to it using `dataTable.Columns.Add` then add your rows using `dataTable.Rows.Add` and then set it as `DataSource` of grid.

**Use without `DataSource`**

DataGridView can work even without datasource. It's enough that you add some columns to DataGidView, then using `datGridView1.Rows.Add` add new rows to it.

Comment: Can you give me a line of code as an example? The message sent is stored in recvDt variable.

Comment: oh i see... i post the comment late. Thank you sir.