# Add items to a specific Column of a ListView in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, multiple-columns

I am creating a WinForms application in visual studio 2017,

I am adding two columns to my ListView,

```
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Column1", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Column2", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```

I am looping a List of strings, I would like to split it in half, where the first half goes to Column1 and the second goes to Column 2.

```
        List<String> strings;
```

I have looked at many soloutions online using subItems instead, I cannot use subItems because:

1. I need all the items to be selectable
2. Some of the strings vary in size, so I would like the columns to be flexible  to be able to display the entire string
3. I need all the strings to be aligned to the left side

A sample of what it should like

```
Column1                Column2           
STRING 1               STRING 100002
STRING 10000           STRING 2222
STRING 144             STRING XCEZ
STRING 144             STRING IK?
STRING 144             STRING 5
```

Does anyone know how to do this ? thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you want to really use a `ListBox` and set it's `MultiColumn` property to `true`. This will give you the multi-columns, each one being selectable, but column width must be uniform

Comment: @JayV, Thank you for your answer. I haven't mentioned on my post that, some strings could have different colours of text, thats why I prefer to use a `ListView`. Also, Iam not sure I could control the size of the columns as expected in the `ListBox`.

Comment: Perhaps a DataGridView would be better for you then?

Comment: @JayV, I have no experience with using a `DataGridView`, would you please show me a sample of using that in relevance to my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have a `List<string>` rather than having a `List<MyClass>`, which `MyClass` has two properties, `Property1` and `Property2`.

Anyway, regarding to your question, you can use a for loop like this:

```
var list = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
var count = list.Count;
listView1.BeginUpdate();
for (var i = 0; i < count / 2; i++)
    listView1.Items.Add(list[i]).SubItems.Add(list[count / 2 + i]);
listView1.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks but, When I run this code, I get  an empty `ListView`. and for the `List<string>` It could be changed, but I haven't used a `List<MyClass>` before, I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Double check your code, you will not receive an empty listview if you are looking into the correct listview and it has some columns added.

Comment: If you don't have experience using classed, so it's time to learn something new which will change your life as a programmer ;)

Comment: I have tried the code that you have posted not my code, just to test the result. I only added,  `PartNumbersListView.View = View.Details;` do I need to add any other properties ?

I am also gonna try the clesses List. :)

Comment: Yes you need some columns as well. You told us you have two columns ...

Comment: Yes sorry, this works, except that the items in the second column are not clickable.

Comment: In list view you cannot select sub-items. You can select items. You can also set `FullRowSelect` to `true`.

Comment: If for any reason you need selectable cells, you need to switch to `DataGridView`

Comment: Yeah, I think I will switch to that. because I need everything to be selectable.

Comment: I strongly recommend you start using a class like what I said.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you,but could you  please show me an example to poulate a `DataGridView` using a `List<Class>` ? :)

Comment: Sure, you will find this post useful: [Can I use DataGridView without using database data?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32576167/3110834)